# Best JavaScript Client Libraries to do OAuth2.0(Google) and access Google CloudEndPoints in phonegap?

Tags: google-app-engine, cordova, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints

I have been developing an online accounting software which is a web application. We use [Secured Google Cloud Endpoints](http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/>) in our project. Now I would like to securely access those endpoints in phonegap. So, for that I would like to do OAuth2.0(google) and access my API securely. I have been struggling for a while to find good JavaScript Client Libraries to access my Secured API in phoneGap.

Please help me...

Any replies would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem with using google's client.js (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js) and Google+ signin?

Comment: While doing authentication, the google apis is sending the origin as 'file://' within the request header. Due to this I was unable to login using google. Is there any way to change domin from file:///android_asset/* to a proper convention ie 'http://wwww.exmaple.com'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally After some struggle I have figured out the solution. If we are trying to do Google OAuth in phone gap its better to use normal JQuery and for calling the Secured Google Cloud Endpoints we can go with Google JavaScript Client Libraries. I have found a sample project [oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery](http://www.itsalif.info/content/oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery) which is a very good start for the beginners.

Comment: oauth-google-api-gapi-phonegap-childbrowser-jquery  this url not found. can you give me something new regading this.